# Angular Proxy absolute URL issue

Tags: angular

I have a working proxy configuration.
So i have my relative request

```
this.httpClient.get("../api/one/two/three")....
```

I use ".." as the app has a configuration like:

```
"www.bizbiz.biz/website/"
```

it gets captured from the proxy:

```
{
     "/api/one/two/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3210",
        "secure": false
     }
}
```

it gets redirected to

```
http://localhost:3210/api/one/two/three
```

And I'm happy.

The problem, is that for the avatars, the back-end sends me an absolute URL from another service which is not available normally and so we have mocked it as well.
I'm unable to tell my Angular application that all the URLs that look like:

```
"http://www.bizzib.biz/api/one/two/avatars/user12.png"
```

Should as well be captured and redirected to the same "http://localhost:3210" like the above (same mock server, different endpoint).
I tried a lot of possible configurations, none of which was successful.
Is it even possible?